# Getting the wrong IP in socket library (Python) - [Getting the information from another adapter]

Tags: python, windows, sockets

I´m using this simple code:

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
'192.168.160.1'
```

The problem is that this is giving me the wrong IP. Doing a simple `ipconfig` I found that is giving me the info from another adapter  (VMWARE related) :

```
Adaptador de Ethernet VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:
   Dirección IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.160.1
Adaptador de LAN inalámbrica Wi-Fi:
   Dirección IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.51
```

I solved it by disabling the `VMware Network Adapter VMnet8`. There is a way to avoid that? Thanks for reading

```
Python 3.8.6
Vmware 16.0.0.63036
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you're trying to find the IP address for the network interface that would be used for internet access?

Something like this gets you that, assuming you're actually connected to the internet:

```
import socket

# create an datagram socket (single UDP request and response, then close)
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
# connect to an address on the internet, that's likely to always be up 
# (the Google primary DNS is a good bet)
sock.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
# after connecting, the socket will have the IP in its address
print(sock.getsockname())
# done
sock.close()
```

Result (on my computer, yours should match your own):

```
('192.168.0.132', 56618)
```

Note: this depends on having an active internet connection and on the service you're connecting to to accept connections. This won't work on an internal network with no internet connection, unless you're trying to connect to an address you can reliably connect to on there (like the router's admin interface, for example)

Comment: Thanks, works perfect! the only problem is the need for an internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `netifaces` package to get the IP address for specific network adapter:

```
import netifaces as ni
ip = ni.ifaddresses('eth0')[ni.AF_INET][0]['addr']
print(ip)
```

You can use any interface in place of 'eth0'

Comment: Do you know how to make it work in Windows? When I try to get the names I receive and long string `7A6EB123-89DC-439A-8975-8EFCFBE8E252` and I try `ip = ni.ifaddresses('A6EB123-89DC-439A-8975-8EFCFBE8E252')[ni.AF_INET][0]['addr']` and doesn`t work

Comment: okey, I solved it putting it like that `ip = ni.ifaddresses('{A6EB123-89DC-439A-8975-8EFCFBE8E252}')[ni.AF_INET][0]['addr']`

Comment: But It,s a different Library... It,s a solution but not THE solution. Thanks u

Comment: The perfect about `socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())` it,s that gives the IP in all computers and contexts.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution with the `netifaces` package recommended by Wasif Hasan, and also can be universal.

```
import netifaces as ni

x = ni.gateways() 
y = x['default'][2][1] 
ip = ni.ifaddresses(y)[ni.AF_INET][0]['addr']
```